# Saving Swift TableView data using NSUSerDefaults

Tags: swift, tableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a tableview in swift. Each cell has a label with different text. When a cell is selected it passes the text to a label on another view controller. I can save this data using a button (Save Data) and load the saved data with another button (Load Data).

My problem is I would ideally like to not use buttons, but have the data loaded automatically when the view loads. However, when I place the NSUSerDefaults code within viewDidLoad (), it saves the data but I am no longer able to change the selection i.e. it loads the first selection permanently. I have posted my code below for the destination ViewController and for the TableViewController.

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!

    var passedValue: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        detailLabel.text = passedValue
    }

    @IBAction func saveDataClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        defaults.setObject(self.detailLabel.text, forKey: "optionValue")
    }

    @IBAction func loadDataClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if let optionValueIsNotNill = defaults.objectForKey("optionValue") as? String {
            self.detailLabel.text = defaults.objectForKey("optionValue") as! String
        }
    }   
}
```

**TableViewController**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var valueToPass:String! 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

        // Get Cell Label
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

        valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel!.text
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailView", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
        if segue.identifier == "showDetailView" {

            // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
            var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
            // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
            viewController.passedValue = valueToPass

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if You want to save selected Data to NSUSerDefaults You should write your saving code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath like this

if you have a function to save the data in NSUserDefaults

```
save(DataArray[indexPath.row])
```

then it will be saved , but i think if your data used when the application is running only , i think the best option to use is static instance .